# Um dos elementos da página se move ao clicar no outro!

Tags: html, css

Não é JavaScript que está fazendo isso que citarei abaixo com minha página, mas sim, o próprio CSS, não sei o que é isso, já tentei resolver 'sem fazer gambiarras', mas não deu certo :(

Vejam por si mesmos, cliquem no botão login, que na verdade é um link, e verão que o outro link ao lado do nome "CRIAR UMA CONTA" também se move. Como resolver?

[Link da página](http://www.ccshop.com.br/prev).

Um [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/m9n08qtu/) reproduzível no JSFiddle.

Comment: O ideal seria você criar um exemplo [Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois quando você consertar o seu site, sua pergunta não fará sentido para mais ninguém e só você terá se beneficiado da sua pergunta. O ideal é que ela sirva de lição para outros usuários com o mesmo problema no futuro.

Comment: Editei sua pergunta para adicionar um exemplo, ele não tá 100% mas acho que já dá pra ter uma ideia. Quem quiser pode melhorá-lo.

Comment: Opa, valeu vou da uma ajeitada aki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não deixe os dois elementos na mesma DIV, separe-os.

Veja como arrumei:

```
<div class="content">
<img src="layout/img/logo_completa.png" alt="CCSHOP" title="CCSHOP - Passagens aéreas e muito mais...">
        <div class="login">
            <a href="#" class="btn-newacc">Criar uma conta</a>
        </div>
        <div class="login">          
            <a href="#" class="btn-login">Fazer Login</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Repare que adicionei mais uma DIV com a classe login, porém ao clicar em um ou em outro o efeito não ocorre para os dois elementos ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Nossa, não tinha pensado nisso kkkk, valeu, para eu não fazer um novo tópico, você sabe como eu faço para que a div com display: table-cell (linha de tabela, eu acho) seja do tamanho dos elementos que está dentro dela, e não com um espaço mais fixo, nunca mexi com tabelas, comecei já no tableless rs, pra entender melhor o site ficou assim: http://www.ccshop.com.br/prev

Comment: @heromax, desconheço como fazer isso que você pediu agora, mas fico feliz em saber que a resposta foi útil quanto ao assunto do tópico.